# How can I fix this error invalid command name "_o10 in NS2

Tags: tcl, ns2

You are missing the MIH / MIPv6 addition provided by `ns-2.29-nist-mob-022707.tgz`.This is for ns-2.29,but I use`ns-allinone-2.35`.Is it the same procedure? Thanks!

This is my code link
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Aan1OeAh5tIeDrt5MjgFTqvNSeahNWVy/view?usp=sharing

While running my tcl script for new protocol in NS2 it shows error as:

```
num_nodes is set 10
invalid command name "Agent/MIHUser/IFMNGMT/MIPV6/Handover/Handover1"
    while executing
"Agent/MIHUser/IFMNGMT/MIPV6/Handover/Handover1 create _o216 "
    invoked from within
"catch "$className create $o $args" msg"
    invoked from within
"if [catch "$className create $o $args" msg] {
if [string match "__FAILED_SHADOW_OBJECT_" $msg] {
delete $o
return ""
}
global errorInfo
error "class $..."
    (procedure "new" line 3)
    invoked from within
"new Agent/MIHUser/IFMNGMT/MIPV6/Handover/Handover1"
    invoked from within
"set handover [new Agent/MIHUser/IFMNGMT/MIPV6/Handover/Handover1]"
    (file "bear2.tcl" line 177)
```

How can I modify it?

Comment: First problem sounds like the object doesn't exist (but which object is not existing isn't clear without the trace from the `errorInfo` global variable; be aware that OTcl traces are confusing at the best of times unlike those from more sophisticated object systems). I don't know why that might be so. Second problem is a syntax error; you don't build lists like that, but rather as `[list $val(x) $val(y)]` or, in a pinch, `"$val(x) $val(y)"`.

Comment: `bear1.tcl` : ~80 lines edited (for typo's). ... Result, see https://www.dropbox.com/s/g7s9l13byjclk5x/BinDer-Yu.tar.gz?dl=0

Comment: `bear2.tcl` »»invalid command name "Agent/MIHUser/IFMNGMT/MIPV6/Handover/Handover1"«« : You are missing the MIH / MIPv6 addition provided by `ns-2.29-nist-mob-022707.tgz` https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/ns-2-35-handoff-between-wifi-and-wimax-4175604225/#7